# Finding SQL data with filters

Tags: java, sql, javafx

So I am developing a flight administration system as a school project, and have hit a wall with a task.

I have to give the opportunity to my customer to search for Multistop flights which consist of direct flights.

A little example: The customer wants a flight from Germany to USA and I have the following two flights:

1. Germany -> Turkey
2. Turkey -> USA

If the customer looks for a multi-stop flight the system has to combine the two flights into one.

So far I can find the two flights and save the name of the Multistop flight into a variable but I have a problem with the SQL statement to find the flights.

My code so far:

Little explanation: startAirportcombo is the starting point selection tool for the first flight. zielTargetAirportcombo is the target.

Method to find the second flight:

```
möglicheFlüge =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ResultSet myRs = pStatement.executeQuery(" select * from flügehin ");

while(myRs.next()) {
    if (myRs.getString("startHinlughafen").equals(startAirportCombo.getValue())
            && myRs.getString("zielHinflughafen").equals(zielAirportCombo.getValue()) == false) {
        tempMultiStopp = myRs.getString("zielHinflughafen");


        if (myRs.getString("startHinlughafen").equals(tempMultiStopp) &&
                myRs.getString("zielHinflughafen").equals(zielAirportCombo.getValue())) {
            multiStop = tempMultiStopp;
        }
    }
}
```

Mthod to find the flights combined and show to customer:

```
if(seatsComboBusiness.getSelectionModel().isEmpty() ||seatsComboEco.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING, "Bitte wählen Sie mindestens einen Sitzplatz aus!");
    alert.setTitle("Fehler");
    alert.showAndWait();
} else {

    if (seatsComboBusiness.getValue() == 0 && seatsComboEco.getValue() == 0) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING, "Bitte wählen Sie mindestens einen Sitzplatz aus!");
        alert.setTitle("Fehler");
        alert.showAndWait();
    } else {

        try {

            // Ablesen
            Statement pStatement = connection.createStatement();
            möglicheFlüge = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ResultSet myRs = pStatement.executeQuery("select * from flügehin where startHinlughafen = \""
                    + startAirportCombo.getValue() + "\" AND anzahlsitzplätzeeco >= \""
                    + seatsComboEco.getValue() + "\" AND anzahlsitzplätzebus >= \""
                    + seatsComboBusiness.getValue() + "\" AND zielHinFlughafen = \""
                    + zielAirportCombo.getValue() + "\" AND ( hinflugdatum = \"" + date.getValue()
                    + "\" OR hinflugdatum = \"" + date.getValue().plusDays(-1) + "\" OR hinflugdatum =\""
                    + date.getValue().plusDays(-2) + "\" OR hinflugdatum =\"" + date.getValue().plusDays(-3)
                    + "\" OR hinflugdatum =\"" + date.getValue().plusDays(1) + "\" OR hinflugdatum =\""
                    + date.getValue().plusDays(2) + "\" OR hinflugdatum =\"" + date.getValue().plusDays(3)
                    + "\" ) "
            );

            while (myRs.next()) {


                möglicheFlüge.add(
                        new InstancedFlightModel(myRs.getInt("flightHinId"), myRs.getString("startHinlugHafen"),
                                myRs.getString("zielHinFlughafen"), myRs.getString("hinflugdatum"),
                                myRs.getString("flugzeug"), myRs.getInt("anzahlsitzplätzeeco"),
                                myRs.getInt("anzahlsitzplätzebus"), myRs.getString("uhrzeitHinflug"),
                                myRs.getFloat("preisEconomy"), myRs.getFloat("preisBusiness"),
                                myRs.getFloat("distanz"), myRs.getString("FGM"), secondDirectFlight()));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,
                    "Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Angaben auf Vollständigkeit");
            alert.setTitle("Kein Flug gefunden");
            alert.showAndWait();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        startAirport.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("startToAirport"));
        multistoppColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("multistopp"));
        targetAirport.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("targetToAirport"));
        flightDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flightDate"));
        flightTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flightTime"));
        airplane.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("airPlane"));
        priceEco.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("priceEconomy"));
        priceBus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("priceBusiness"));
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flightNumber"));
        airline.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fluggesellschaft"));
        distanz.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("distance"));

        table.setItems(möglicheFlüge);
        if (möglicheFlüge.isEmpty()) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING,
                    "Es konnte auf Basis Ihrer Eingaben kein passender Flug gefunden werden.");
            alert.setTitle("Kein Flug gefunden");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problems lie in SQL statement in the final method but the "multistop" variable stays null in the end. So maybe someone can help me or give me a pointer?

Comment: Short feedback to you sql statement creation: you should always use prepared statements where possible instead of string concatenation! String concatenation opens your application to sql injections.

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback I am pretty new to sql and java thats why I dont really know the best ways to do it an now I am just trying to accomplish my school project while learning but I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 0):

You can do this SQL too. I am assuming the table name is "flight", see the SQL below. Pass in the search condition for origin and destination to this SQL. It will find flights with 0 or 1 connection.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
select origin, destination
from flight
where origin = ?
) a INNER JOIN
(
select origin, destination
from flight
where destination = ?
) b
ON a.destination = b.origin       
;
```

Answer (score -1):

So I could fix the problem of the flights not being foung. But now the Problem is that multi Stopp is always changed. Example I have the following three flights.

1. Germany - Usa
2. Germany - Turkey
3. Turkey - Usa
4. Germany - China

Now if the customer searches for germany - usa the multistopp becomes china even though there is no flight from China to USa. This is the upodated version of the method to find the other flights. I had to rename the resultset to fix my first problem.

```
        Statement pStatement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet myRs2 = pStatement.executeQuery("select * from flügehin "
            );


        while (myRs2.next()) {

            if (myRs2.getString("startHinlughafen").equals(startAirportCombo.getValue())
                    && myRs2.getString("zielHinflughafen").equals(zielAirportCombo.getValue()) == false) {
                tempMultiStopp = myRs2.getString("zielHinflughafen");
            }
                else {
                    tempMultiStopp = null;
                }

                if (myRs2.getString("startHinlughafen").equals(tempMultiStopp)
                        && myRs2.getString("zielHinflughafen").equals(zielAirportCombo.getValue())) {
                    multiStop = tempMultiStopp;
                }

            }
```

Comment: If your original question is answered and you have a new problem, try spending some time solving it yourself. If you can't solve it after spending some time on it, ask a new question.  StackOverflow is not designed to handle dynamic questions.